# Similarly triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$\triangle ABC$, Let Incircle $\triangle ABC$ touch $BC,CA$ and $AB$ at $D,E,F$ respectively.
Let line $AD$ cut an incircle at point $X$ and line $XB$ and $XC$ cut incircle at point $Y$ and $Z$ respectively.
If $AX=XD$ ,show that $EY=FZ$

I know If $\triangle CEZ \sim \triangle CAX$ and $\triangle BFY \sim \triangle BAX$ , then $EZ//AD//FY$.
It follow that $EY=FZ$ . But I have no idea to prove that $\triangle CEZ \sim \triangle CAX$ and $\triangle BFY \sim \triangle BAX$.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I noticed that $DX$, $EY$ and $FZ$ meet in the midpoint between $D$ and $X$, but don't have a good idea on how to use that. I believe I could write a coordinate-based proof, but I'll wait a while, see whether someone else comes up with something more elegant.

Comment: @MvG Assume your finding is true, the problem is solved. Let DX, EY and FZ meet at T, the midpoint of XD. Let I be in-center. Then, A, F, T, I, E are con-cyclic. Therefore, AB // EZ because $\angle CEZ = \angle EFZ = \angle TAE$.

Comment: @MvG Correction. should be AX // EZ.

Comment: I can prove that AD, EY and FZ concur in a general case. However, I still don't know how to use it in case AX=XD.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a problem B2 from 10th Iberoamerican Mathematical Olympiad (1995). Several different solutions can be found at AOPS:

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h4954p15699

Also don't miss the solution given on a different page (it could well be the simplest):

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3496